# Как использовать классы контсрукторов с гетерами и сетерами оъектов с приминением Spring java?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Подскажите, как использовать Soring DI в Java с применением конструктора. К примеру интерфейс Enimal.java

```
public interfase Enimal(){
   void say();
}
```

И есть 2 реализации этого интерфейса: Cat.java & Dog.java:

```
public class Cat implement Enimal{
   public void say(){
      System.out.println("Say myau");
   }
}

public class Dog implement Enimal{
   public void say(){
      System.out.println("Say gav");
   }
}
```

И есть Service для работы с классами высше:

```
public class ModelService{
   private Enimal enimal;
   public ModelService(Enimal enimal){
      this.enimal = enimal;
   }

   public void saySomething(){
      enumal.say();
   }
}
```

Как я могу каждый раз раз создавать объект ModelService с передачей разных объектов? К примеру, сейчас мне нужно использовать класс Cat, а дальше необходимо заюзать Dog?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что Вы имеете ввиду. Спринг это фреймворк, а не язык. Для вызова методов и конструкторов используется синтаксис Java.

Comment: @not a Programmer просто пытаюсь изучать спринг, по этому ещё не совсем все понимаю. Например я создаю объект с контекста, с помощью метода getBean, конфигурация с помощью аннотаций, в классе имеется конструктор с параметрами, как я могу создать объект с контекста и передать параметры в этот конструктор?

Comment: Если это обьект, который Вы получаете из контекста, то конструктор вызывать не нужно (Spring это делает за Вас)

Comment: @notaProgrammer окей, а что если необходимо создать этот объект с конструктором, только в констуруктор динамиески передать паремтры (например, если есть интерфейс, и 2 реализации этого интерфейса), то как я смогу каждый раз создавать его с разными реализациями?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример, чтобы я четко понимал что Вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: @notaProgrammer я изменил описание вопроса, думаю сейчас должно быть понятнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    // Обьявляем бин с типом Enimal и id - "enimal" (из названия метода)
    @Bean
    public Enimal enimal() {
        Enimal enimal = new Cat():
        // Если нужно использовать Dog
        // Enimal enimal = new Dog():
        return enimal;
    }

    // Обьявляем бин ModelService, чтобы Spring смог внедрить в него бин с типом Enimal (если используете Spring Boot это не нужно)
    @Bean
    public ModelService modelService(Enimal enimal /*получаем бин enimal из контекста*/) {
        return new ModelService(enimal);
    }
}
```

Comment: то есть для каждой реализации этого конструктора, с каждым из класов которые реализовали интерфейс Enimal необходимо создать отдельный класс конфигурации, верно? И хотел еще спросить, может можете подсказать какой то проект на Гитхабе opensource, что бы можно было набраться опыта со SpringFramework?

Comment: Нет, в одном конфигурационном файле можно обьявить сколько угодно бинов. Почитайте лучше Spring in Action, замечательная книга.